# Is it possible to create a CakePHP model that doesn't refer to a table from the database?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I'm developing an API for C2DM to send push messages to Android devices. I have the API in PHP5 and I want to tranform it to CakePHP 2.0.

How can I create a model in CakePHP that doesn't refer to a table in the database? Is it possible to create such a model and a controller to manage it?

Or is there any existing code to do Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) in CakePHP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set `$useTable` to `false` in that particular tableless model, [see the cookbook for further details](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usetable).

Comment: and of course i can declare some attributes and some getters and setters, and use one of the models which they refer to some table on the database ??

Comment: Yes, if you configured your model relations correctly you should be able to get data from other models with relevant database tables.

Answer (score 3):

cakephp models have an attribute called $useTable which you can set to false.